# Add Item to Sub-Array in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```js
vm.prdGroups = [{
  type_id: '1',
  group_name: '',
  is_required: false,
  position: 0,
  options: {
    item_name: '',
    item_price: '',
    position: 0

  }
}];
```

How do I add a new array to the options key, to have something like this

```js
vm.prdGroups = [{
  type_id: '1',
  group_name: '',
  is_required: false,
  position: 0,
  options: {
    item_name: '',
    item_price: '',
    position: 0
  },
  {
    item_name: '',
    item_price: '',
    position: 0
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is your vm.prdGroups.options is not a array. You need to make it a array and then push new values to it.

```js
let vm={};
vm.prdGroups = [{
  type_id: '1',
  group_name: '',
  is_required: false,
  position: 0,
  options: {
    item_name: '',
    item_price: '',
    position: 0

  }
}];

let temp= vm.prdGroups[0].options;
vm.prdGroups[0].options = []
vm.prdGroups[0].options.push(temp,'some other object');
console.log(vm.prdGroups);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my options wasn't actually an array, so I couldn't possibly *push* to it, I made it an array, and it made the task doable

```
  vm.prdGroups = [
                {
                    type_id: 1,
                    group_name: '',
                    is_required: false,
                    position: 0,
                    options: [{
                        item_name: '',
                        item_price: '',
                        position: 0
                    }]
                }
            ];
```

And I could push to the array inside an array with the use of index, so the method to push was this

```
 vm.addPrdItem = function (index) {
            console.log(index);
            var itemLength = vm.prodAttribs.product_groups[index].options.length - 1;
            vm.productItems = {
                item_name: '',
                item_price: '',
                position: itemLength + 1
            };
            vm.product_groups[index].options.push(vm.productItems);
        }
```

Thanks to all who answered, appreciate.